# How to select only duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the table in sql server.. and below is what I want to do.

TABLE:

```
Area (column 1)
-----
Oregon
California
California
California
Oregon
Washington
Idaho
Washington
```

I want ALL the cities that *are* duplicates to be returned, but not the distinct ones. Just the duplicates. Is there a select statement that lets me return only duplicates?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Select State FROM Area
GROUP BY State
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Try this

Update the query with your own column and table names

Answer (score 1):

While the `GROUP BY .. HAVING` approach is probably better here, this case - "more than one" - can also be answered with a `JOIN` *assuming* that there is a column (or set of columns) that form a Key. The requirement of a Key is that it must *uniquely* identify a record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.State
FROM AREA a1
JOIN AREA a2
  ON a1.AreaId != a2.AreaId  -- assume there is a Key to join on
  AND a1.State = a2.State    -- and such that different Areas with same State
```

Comment: @NISAR Then an appropriate Key is not being used (State can't be used as a key because it does not *uniquely* identify a record).

Comment: Thanks .. but your code take 93% query cost relative to this code takes 7% below....
"Select State FROM Area GROUP BY State Having COUNT(*) > 1"

Answer (score -1):

select count(area),area_id from [Table_Name] group by area_id  having count(area) > 1